# jquery sort based on classname not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I want to sort my divs based on the classname, here's what I have so far:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="blue">1</div>
    <div class="red">2</div>
    <div class="red">3</div>
    <div class="blue">4</div>
    <div class="blue">5</div>
    <div class="red">6</div>
    <div class="blue">7</div>
</div>

var elem = $('#container').find('div').sort(sortMe);

function sortMe(a, b) {
    return a.className < b.className;
}
$('#container').append(elem);

.red {
    color:red;
}

.blue{
    color:blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bekvLhm7/

Based on this I would expect my output to look like:

```
2
3
6
1
4
5
7
```

But even after running the code it doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `return a.toLocaleCompare(b);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return 1 or -1 in the sorting comparator:

```js
var elem = $('#container').find('div').sort(sortMe);

function sortMe(a, b) {
  return a.className < b.className ? 1 : -1;
}

$('#container').append("<br/>");
$('#container').append(elem.clone());
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div class="red">2</div>
  <div class="red">3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div class="red">6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```